# How to move Filters Pane to the left from right in power-bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-filters

I have a Power-bi report created in Power-bi Desktop and embedded to my custom web page. The filters pane is on the right of the report by default. Is there a way to move it the left of the report instead? I could not find how to manage this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move it to the other side.  I'm guessing when this is pushed out to GA or at some point in the future it'll be an option, but currently this is all you can change on the Filter Pane:

**Pane Options**
Background color
Background transparency
Filter pane border on or off
Filter pane border color
Filter pane title and header font, color, and text size

**Card Options**
Background color
Background transparency
Border: on or off
Border color
Font, color, and text size
Input box color

[Taken from here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-report-filter-preview)